# Apache Wicket spinner.js best practice

Tags: javascript, wicket

I am looking for a way to implement spinner.js in my code. Do not really have an idea how to get this running. Background: I have a page where I offer a download which can take a while because a document is beeing generated in background. Is there any out of the box component I can use to visualize to the user that a proccess is still running an he has to wait? I know there is ModalDialog but sorry to say that it's is ugly. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your page implement the IAjaxIndicatorAware interface to use busy indicators for ajax requests. Or you can simply use an IndicatingAJaxLink (or IndicatingAjaxButton) which are examples of implementation of the IAjaxIndicatorAware (allowing the display of a spinner during the execution of the process).